# Setup Azure Function proxy with Azure Service fabric

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I would like to setup proxy in Azure Functions with Azure Service fabric. when i browse 
http://tktestfnc.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/api/values
I get the output.

But when I try this
http://tktestfunc.azurewebsites.net/myweb/api/values
it gives page not found

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "tktestweb": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/myweb",
                "methods": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "http://tktestfnc.westus.cloudapp.azure.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Have I configured it correctly?

Comment: It works on my machine.. both addresses return a response.

Comment: I'm getting results for both. I suggest you, check Working with Azure Functions Proxies:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies  and samples:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/functions-js-spa/  see if you have missed any configuration or steps.

Comment: Both URLs work for me as well